# html text element has weird height

Tags: html, css

I'm making a Mobile web page and I'm faced with a weird situation.
The web site is showing different layouts on local and server, but the HTML and CSS is the same.
You can ignore `<` and `X` buttons - they are not related to this situation

-local

[image]

-server

[image]

here is my HTML:

```html
<h1>
  <span class="tit">이전 화면으로 돌아가기</span>
</h1>
```

and my CSS (include inherit style):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #454c52;
  padding: 18px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.25;
  color: #000;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

h1 .tit {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, why not trying positioning the span into absolute and make it center. Just set a fixed height on h1.

See code below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #454c52;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  height: 70px;
}

h1 .tit {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="tit">이전 화면으로 돌아가기</span>
</h1>
```

EDITS:
Or try put all your CSS code into h1. This is so that the span inside will inherit the CSS.

Please see code below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  background: #454c52;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 18px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="tit">이전 화면으로 돌아가기</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: I know if I use position or fixed height, its work. but I want to know the reason of that situation. :)

Comment: Ah I get it. Please take a look at my answer, I have some edits there.

Comment: ah! I tried what you said, and then I found the reason. reason is font-size. <h1> had 2em font-size, so I changed font-size to 14px, then it works correctly

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure that why you can see the UI in your local.

First of all, flex layout is a better solution.

For your situation, I think it's caused by span tag (inline). It works if you use div tag(block) instead. Please have a try.

Sugget to use flex layout here:

```css
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #454c52;
    padding: 18px 0;
}
.flex-container .icon{
    min-width: 25px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.flex-container .title {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="icon"><svg focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"></path></svg></div>
  <div class="title">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="icon"><svg focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"></path></svg></div>
</div>
```